# Postfix Sender address rejected: Access denied

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I install postfix and smtp server with http://www.pixelinx.com/2010/10/creating-a-mail-server-on-ubuntu-using-postfix-courier-ssltls-spamassassin-clamav-and-amavis/ tutorial.

But i can not send and recive mail, I check with www.mxtoolbox.com smtp and is the same: Sender address rejected: Access denied [156 ms]

what this means? I am reading here: http://www.penpublishing.com/support/emailerrors/understandingemailerrors/default.aspx

but with no solution for me...

```
EHLO please-read-policy.mxtoolbox.com
250-mail.domain.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN [140 ms]
MAIL FROM: <supertool@mxtoolbox.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok [546 ms]
RCPT TO: <test@example.com>
554 5.7.1 <supertool@mxtoolbox.com>: Sender address rejected: Access denied [156 ms]
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye [156 ms]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've configured postfix like it says in that tutorial, and you have your sender restrictions identical to the tutorial:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject
```

You won't be able to send unless you authenticate using the AUTH command or you are part of the `mynetworks` list, which in the tutorial is:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
```

Which means you can only send form localhost if you don't SASL authenticate. Here's a list of restrictions for `smtpd_sender_restrictions`: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restrictions

Essentially, you want a `permit` at the end if you want to be able to send mail, but be careful not to make it *too* easy. You can do a search for "postfix smtpd_recipient_restrictions examples" to get some sane examples.

Comment: thank you. So I need to use AUTH command. This is by using SSL or how can I do this?

Comment: @mbrc The AUTH is an Extended SMTP command (see in your transcript: `250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN` and `250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN`). It's handled by email clients when you set the "SMTP Server Requires Authentication" checkbox/flag.

Comment: Even I use SSL and 465 port I can not send mails in outlook but as you said, I can send it by web client.

Comment: I see that you replay the same time I did :) And where in outlook or thunderbir i can set "SMTP Server Requires Authentication"?

Comment: @mbrc I've never used either of those email clients before, but that's irrelevant to your question (and guessing by your further questions, you may not have even setup SASL user accounts so authenticating with SMTP may not help). By ending the `smtpd_sender_restrictions` chain with `permit` instead of `reject` fixes your problem. You should read through the postfix documentation about sender restrictions.

Comment: [google search of "smtp authentication outlook"](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=smtp+authentication+outlook&oq=smtp+authentication+outlook&gs_l=hp.3..0l7j0i30l3.474.6471.0.6998.40.27.1.3.3.5.659.7180.6j6j1j1j7j4.27.0...0.0...1c.eZXu0JpkBs0)

Comment: [google search of "smtp authentication thunderbird"](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=smtp+authentication+thunderbird&oq=smtp+authentication+thunderbird&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i30l6j0i5j0i5i30l2.31163.32514.0.32604.11.7.0.0.0.0.203.709.2j3j1.6.0...0.0...1c.yh5obeEhK24)

Comment: I am reading and searching for two days but I didn't want to change this becouse tutorial didn't say anything about this. So if I want to use clients then I must change smtpd_sender_restrictions, smtpd_client_restrictions, smtpd_recipient_restrictions?

Comment: I change to permit and now I can send mail but I can not receive it... damn

Comment: @mbrc That's technically a different question but you need to do something similar to `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`, the `reject` at the end is doing the same thing, e.g. preventing you from *receiving* mail.

Comment: huh that is hard. I am reading but if I remove all restrictions and just add permit I get: fatal: parameter "smtpd_recipient_restrictions": specify at least one working instance of: check_relay_domains, reject_unauth_destination, reject, defer or defer_if_permit. Strange is that in old domain everything works at first...

Comment: i add now smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination and working. Thank you for big help. You save my day :)

Comment: You don't want an explicit "permit" at the end of smtpd_SENDER_restrictions, nor is that the place to put SASL checks...